# Angular : how to re-render compiled template after model update?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on an angular form builder which generate a json.
Everything works fine except one thing.

You can find an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/dJRS5/8/

HTML :

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div class='formBuilderWrapper' id='builderDiv' ng-controller="FormBuilderCtrl" >
        <div class='configArea' data-ng-controller="elementDrag">    
            <h2>drag/drop</h2>
            <form name="form" novalidate class='editBloc'>
                <div data-ng-repeat="field in fields" class='inputEdit'>
                    <data-ng-switch on="field.type">
                        <div class='labelOrder' ng-class='{column : !$last}' drag="$index" dragStyle="columnDrag" drop="$index" dropStyle="columnDrop">{{field.type}}
                        </div>
                        <label for="{{field.name}}" data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="field.caption"></label>

                        <input data-ng-switch-when="Text" type="text" placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" data-ng-model="field.value" />

                        <p data-ng-switch-when="Text/paragraph" data-ng-model="field.value" data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="field.paragraph"></p>

                            <span data-ng-switch-when="Yes/no question">
                                <p data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="field.yesNoQuestion"></p>
                                <input type='radio' name="yesNoQuestion" id="yesNoQuestion_yes" value="yesNoQuestion_yes" />
                                <label for="yesNoQuestion_yes">Oui</label>
                                <input type='radio' name="yesNoQuestion" id="yesNoQuestion_no" value="yesNoQuestion_no"/>
                                <label for="yesNoQuestion_no">Non</label>
                            </span>     
            <p data-ng-switch-when="Submit button" class='submit' data-ng-model="field.value">
                    <input value="{{field.name}}" type="submit">
                </p>                        
                    </data-ng-switch>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>        
        <div id='previewArea' data-ng-controller="formWriterCtrl">
            <h2>preview</h2>    
            <div data-ng-repeat="item in fields" content="item" class='templating-html'></div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS :

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('FormBuilderCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.fields = [{"type":"Text/paragraph","paragraph":"hello1"},{"type":"Yes/no question","yesNoQuestion":"following items must be hidden","yes":"yes","no":"no"},{"type":"Text/paragraph","paragraph":"hello2"},{"type":"Submit button","name":"last item"}]  ;
    }]);


    app.controller('elementDrag', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
        $rootScope.$on('dropEvent', function(evt, dragged, dropped) {
            if($scope.fields[dropped].type == 'submitButton' || $scope.fields[dragged].type == 'submitButton'){
                return;
            }
            var tempElement = $scope.fields[dragged];
            $scope.fields[dragged] = $scope.fields[dropped];
            $scope.fields[dropped] = tempElement;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }]);

    app.directive("drag", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
        function dragStart(evt, element, dragStyle) {
            if(element.hasClass('column')){
                element.addClass(dragStyle);
                evt.dataTransfer.setData("id", evt.target.id);
                evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            }
        };
        function dragEnd(evt, element, dragStyle) {
            element.removeClass(dragStyle);
        };
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs)  {
                if(scope.$last === false){
                    attrs.$set('draggable', 'true');
                    scope.dragStyle = attrs["dragstyle"];
                    element.bind('dragstart', function(evt) {
                        $rootScope.draggedElement = scope[attrs["drag"]];
                        dragStart(evt, element, scope.dragStyle);
                    });
                    element.bind('dragend', function(evt) {
                        dragEnd(evt, element, scope.dragStyle);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }]);

    app.directive("drop", ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        function dragEnter(evt, element, dropStyle) {
            element.addClass(dropStyle);
            evt.preventDefault();
        };
        function dragLeave(evt, element, dropStyle) {
            element.removeClass(dropStyle);
        };
        function dragOver(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        };
        function drop(evt, element, dropStyle) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            element.removeClass(dropStyle);
        };
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs)  {
                if(scope.$last === false){
                    scope.dropStyle = attrs["dropstyle"];
                    element.bind('dragenter', function(evt) {
                        dragEnter(evt, element, scope.dropStyle);
                    });
                    element.bind('dragleave', function(evt) {
                        dragLeave(evt, element, scope.dropStyle);
                    });
                    element.bind('dragover', dragOver);
                    element.bind('drop', function(evt) {
                        drop(evt, element, scope.dropStyle);
                        var dropData = scope[attrs["drop"]];
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('dropEvent', $rootScope.draggedElement, dropData);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }]);



    app.controller('formWriterCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){

    }]);  


    app.directive('templatingHtml', function ($compile) {
        var previousElement;
        var previousIndex;
        var i=0;
        var inputs = {};

        var paragraphTemplate = '<p data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="content.paragraph"></p>';    
        var noYesQuestionTemplate = '<p data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="content.yesNoQuestion"></p><input id="a__index__yes" type="radio" name="a__index__"><label for="a__index__yes" />{{content.yes}}</label><input id="a__index__no" class="no" type="radio" name="a__index__" /><label for="a__index__no">{{content.no}}</label>';
        var submitTemplate = '<p class="submit"><input value="{{content.name}}" type="submit" /></p>';

        var getTemplate = function(contentType, contentReplace, contentRequired) {
            var template = '';
            switch(contentType) {
                case 'Text/paragraph':
                    template = paragraphTemplate;
                    break;
                case 'Yes/no question':
                    template = noYesQuestionTemplate;
                    break;
            case 'Submit button':
                    template = submitTemplate;
                    break;
            }

            template = template.replace(/__index__/g, i);        
            return template;
        }

        var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            i++;
            elementTemplate = getTemplate(scope.content.type);
            element.html(elementTemplate);
            if(previousElement == 'Yes/no question'){
                element.children().addClass('hidden');
                element.children().addClass('noYes'+previousIndex); 
            }
            if(scope.content.type == 'Yes/no question'){
                previousElement = scope.content.type;
                previousIndex = i; 
            }
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }

        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: linker,
            scope:{
                content:'='
            }
        };
    });
```

On the example there are 2 areas :
    - the first one does a ngRepeat on Json and allow to reorder items with drag and drop
    - the second area also does a ngRepeat, it is a preview templated by a directive using compile function. Some elements are hidden if they are after what I called "Yes/no question"

Here is an example of Json generated by the form builder :

```
$scope.fields = 

[{"type":"Text/paragraph","paragraph":"hello1"},{"type":"Yes/no question","yesNoQuestion":"following items must be hidden","yes":"yes","no":"no"},  
 {"type":"Text/paragraph","paragraph":"hello2"},{"type":"Submit button","name":"last item"}]  ;
```

When the page load everything is ok, Hello1 is visible and Hello2 is hidden.

But when I drop Hello1 after "Yes/no question", dom elements are reorganised but Hello1 is not hidden.
I think it comes from $compile but I don't know how to resolve it.

Could you help me with this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I only see you setting the 'hidden' class on the element based on that rule (after a yes/no) in the link function. That's only called once for the DOM element - when it's first created. Updating the data model doesn't re-create the element, it updates it in place. You would need a mechanism that does re-create it if you wanted to do it this way.

I see three ways you can do this:

1. In your linker function, listen for the same `dropEvent` that you listen for above. This is more efficient than you'd think (it's very fast) and you can re-evaluate whether to apply this `hidden` class or not.
2. Use something like ngIf or literally re-creating it in your collection to force the element to be recreated entirely. This is not as efficient, but sometimes is still desirable for various reasons.
3. If your use case is actually this simple (if this wasn't a redux of something more complicated you're trying to do) you could use CSS to do something like this. A simple rule like

   ```
   .yes-no-question + .text-paragraph { display: none; }
   ```

   using a sibling target could handle this directly without as much work. This is much more limited in what it can do, obviously, but it's the most efficient option if it covers what you need.